# ¿Se puede crear un trigger que modifique 2 tablas?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Pasa que estoy haciendo un sistema de control de inventario en Laravel 7.x el cual tiene su almacén de materiales y en una vista hago petición de materiales o préstamo de materiales que hacen los trabajadores (esa parte la tengo hecha) lo que no se, es como puedo retornar el material** que pide un trabajador** (A continuación mando como tengo mis tablas para hacer la petición de material)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea era o es hacer un trigger que al momento de hacer la eliminación de un registro de la tabla de peticion_materials antes de eliminar modificara la tabla materiales retornando la cantidad del material pedido y después de.. eliminar los detalles.

¿Estoy muy perdido? ¿O como podría retornar materiales? Acepto sugerencias por favor

Comment: Lo intentaste? Cómo? Qué pasó cuando se ejecutó tu trigger? Con qué datos probaste?

Comment: Lo intente pero me arroja error proble con el id en comun que es id_peticion

Comment: Entonces pon el código de tu intento y el error completo, EN la pregunta, por favor :)